# Best way to use Babel to create a single JavaScript bundle

Tags: javascript, html, file, bundle, babeljs

I have differents JSfiles and I have to use Babel to create a single JS bundle.

They recommended me this 1st link, but I don't understand how to: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Browsing in the internet I found this 2nd link: http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/babel-webpack/ which obligates me to use this third one first: http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/setup-babel/

Are 2nd and 3rd links a viable form for learning how to create a single JS bundle? Is there any other good and easy option?

Comment: Babel is not for bundling files.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if you can use babel as a bundler. However since you are new, I suggest looking in to webpack. If this is an option, read on

Your folder structure can be initially something similar to below

```
project folder
  |
  |-src
  |  |
  |  |- index.js
  |  |- moduleOne.js
  |  |- moduleTwo.js
  |
  |- index.html
  |- webpack.config.js
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    content
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

*moduleOne.js*

```
export default class moduleOne {

    constructor() {
        console.log('moduleOne constructor');
    }

    someFunc(text){
        console.log(text);
    }
}
```

*moduleTwo.js*

```
export default class moduleTwo {

    constructor() {
        console.log('moduleTwo constructor');
    }

    someFunc(text){
        console.log(text);
    }
}
```

on a command line window, navigate to project folder and type `npm install webpack --save-dev`

then run `webpack` to bundle files. This will create a `dist` folder with `bundle.js` file in it.

Now if you open the `index.html` on browser, you should see following console output.

```
moduleOne constructor
moduleTwo constructor
moduleOne.someFunc
moduleTwo.someFunc
```

In a nutshell, `index.js` imported `moduleOne.js` and `moduleTwo.js`, instantiated them and called the `someFunc()` method. Webpack bundled all this in to `dist/bundle.js`. This is a quick setup but hopefully you'll get the idea

Source: [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)